# as3 score counter giving error #1006: value is not a function when called from a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

In the main timeline I have the code:

```
stop();

var score = 0;
scorecounter.text = score;

function updateScore() {
    scorecounter.text = ++score;
}
```

and inside a movieclip on frame 10 I have the code:

```
gotoAndPlay(1);    
this(parent).updatescore();
```

which returns in the output panel

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
```

I'm pretty new to flash and have no what is wrong with the code.
any and all help will be appreciated, thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` keyword is not a function. Instead you could do `MovieClip(parent).updateScore();`

Comment: In addition, it should be `updateScore()` not `updatescore()`; note the uppercase S.

Comment: Tried what you said, this time it returned :    Symbol 'character', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 24, Line 2 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method character.

Comment: oh wait, this worked.  I was putting the instance name instead of MovieClip. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In AS3, we reach to an objects parent with *dot syntax*
So corrent sytax would be;

```
this.parent.yourFunction();
```

But in your case, it will not work. Because you cannot refer to a function in main timeline like that.

Instead, try exploring as3 OOP principles.